# Is it possible to pass a function on input to another component in Polymer

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I want to refactor my code on smart and dumb components (logic and presentation components) and I'm wondering if it's possible to pass function in input and trigger it from the host component (as in Angular for example).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I took this approach to have a component for model data and a separate filtering component with toggles that would pass a function to the model component via a propery like so:

```
<my-model id="modelData" items="{{items}}" filters="{{filters}}"></my-model>

<my-filter id="listFilter" active-filter="{{filters}}"></my-filter>
```

inside `<my-filter>`:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    activeFilter: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true
    }
  }
}

apply() {
  this.activeFilter = this._compute(this.$.myToggle.value)
}

_compute(toggle) {
  return function(item) {
    return item.condition == toggle
  }
}
```

inside `<my-model>`:

```
_filterModel(model, filters) {
  for (let item of model) {
    if (filters(item)) {
      this.push('filteredList', item)
    }
  }
}
```

Although I made it this way just as a proof of concept, as normally I would just pass around the object to be modified.